# Use Terminal Server to play on-hold music

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a windows server 2008 R2 terminal server that is the only thing in the room with a sound card. Is it possible to have it play an mp3 file as a background service so we can play on-hold music and remotely change the file?

Our previous server had an account auto-login for other reasons so we just put the mp3 in the startup group. Now we don't need that auto-login and R2 doesn't let you.

Comment: Do you really need to be able to change the music remotely? Honestly I think the time you'll spend getting this to work flawlessly is worth far more than the money you'd spend just buying one of [these](http://www.onholdplus.com/products/OHP-8000).

Comment: If we can get it working we can roll it out to a dozen stores with the same configuration across the country. Some of them currently play off of mp3 players and that's a plan B but it'd be better to not have to do that.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Are you sure about auto logon? I have a 2008R2 server that does this, but it's also not running RDS.

Comment: Well following the guides there's a checkbox that doesn't even exist on R2. There might be a way to do it though registry...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to encrypt credentials to the registry for the system to use to log on at boot, and this can easily be accomplished using a Sysinternals utility:

## [Autologon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx)

I am successfully using this utility with a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance currently.

The only caveat appears to be the following:

> Note: When Exchange Activesync password restrictions are in place, Windows will not process the autologon configuration.